# What is anti-aliasing in rendering an image in python?

Tags: python, pygame

What is anti-aliasing?
When I render an image with pygame module the after the text it asks for anti-aliasing, so i wanted to know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to explain [Anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing_filter) is to show the difference between anti aliasing on and off.
Compare text rendering with and without anti-aliasing:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, anti-aliasing has reduced the jaggedness and created a "smoother" look. This is achieved by blending the pixels on the edge of the text with the background. The jaggs are not completely opaque, but are partially transparent.

Example code:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 150))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 100)
#text = font.render('Hello World', False, (255, 0, 0))
text = font.render('Hello World', True, (255, 0, 0))

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
ts, w, h, c1, c2 = 50, *window.get_size(), (128, 128, 128), (64, 64, 64)
tiles = [((x*ts, y*ts, ts, ts), c1 if (x+y) % 2 == 0 else c2) for x in range((w+ts-1)//ts) for y in range((h+ts-1)//ts)]
for rect, color in tiles:
    pygame.draw.rect(background, color, rect)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.blit(background, (0, 0))
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The above image explains everything.
Anti-aliasing is better for pixel-art games.

Answer (score 0):

Aliasing is an undesirable effect that causes image artifacts. You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). When you are decreasing resolution of an image, then you are downsampling it, which can introduce aliasing. There are algorithms to decrease/remove aliasing (at a cost of some additional computations) - this is what term "anti-aliasing" refers to.